# Trying to create Hello World Watch App - LaunchServicesError 0

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

I'm trying to create a simple Watch project. Created a project in Xcode. Did not add any code or assets. Just trying to run in the simulator.
I get the following the error

The operation couldn't be completed
(LaunchservicesErrr error 0)

The simulator log show.. this... any ideas?

Nov 29 14:01:32 Jons-MBP syncdefaultsd[28597]: (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null)
Nov 29 14:01:32 Jons-MBP syncdefaultsd[28597]: (Note ) SYDAccount: no account
Nov 29 14:01:32 Jons-MBP syncdefaultsd[28597]: (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null)
Nov 29 14:01:37 Jons-MBP SpringBoard[28541]: Weekly asset update check did fire (force=NO)
Nov 29 14:01:37 Jons-MBP SpringBoard[28541]: Beginning check for asset updates (force: 0
Nov 29 14:01:37 Jons-MBP SpringBoard[28541]: Did not complete check for asset updates (force: 0, isVoiceOverRunning: 0
Nov 29 14:01:55 Jons-MBP lsd[28561]: LaunchServices: Currently 0 installed placeholders: (

Comment: Which target have you started? Sometimes it helps first start the iOS target and later the watch target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if your watchkit extensions bundle ID isn't prefixed with your app's bundle ID. For example if you app is com.mycompany.appname, your watchkitapp should be something like com.mycompany.appname.watchkitapp, and your watchkitextension should be com.mycompany.appname.watchkitapp.watchkitextension. 
You can also reset your simulator.